# Arduino Serial.readBytes() Incompatible Types

Tags: c, arduino

When I do this on Arduino:

```
const unsigned long baudrate = 57600;


const int TledPin = 13;

//---------------------------------------------------------------
void setup() {
  //Serial.begin(baudrate);      // Identifies VCP module
  Serial2.begin(baudrate);      // Identifies UART2  SNAP module
  Serial3.begin(baudrate);      // Identifies UART3  RN42 modem

  pinMode(TledPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(SHDN_PWR, OUTPUT);      


  digitalWrite(SHDN_PWR, HIGH);     // Turn wireless board regulator ON

} 
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------

void loop() {
    char rxdata[14];
   if (Serial2.available() > 0){      // Read from SNAP write to RN42
              Serial2.readBytes(rxData, 14);
              Serial3.write(rxData);
              //Serial3.write(Serial2.read());
   }

}
```

I get the following errors:

```
BT_SNAP_SoftConnectV2.ino: In function 'void loop()':
BT_SNAP_SoftConnectV2:47: error: 'rxData' was not declared in this scope
BT_SNAP_SoftConnectV2:55: error: incompatible types in assignment of 'int' to 'char [14]'
```

In the Arduino documentation it says that Serial.readBytes(buffer, length) accepts a char[] and an int so I don't understand the error.

Could somebody explain this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

typo: `rxData` is not the same as `rxdata` (which is what you declared the array as).

for the second error, you've not included the code - from your sample, you've only included up to line 52, but the error is on 55.

Comment: Sorry, I know my mistake now - I wasn't thinking straight.